# Why arent Qasim, Abdullah, Ibrahim and Mohsin not considered among imams?

Tags: shiism, ahl-ul-bayt

Qasim, Abdullah were born to Khadijah from loins of Prophet, Ibrahim to Maryam, prophets slave.

Muhsin was third son of Fatima and Ali.

My question is Hassan, Hussain are taken as imams, why arent Qasim or abdullah or muhsin not considered among imams?

Google search isnt giving anything.

If the 12 imams are given thrones in hereafter, why arent the above 4 given thrones?

Comment: You do realize all three of the Prophet's sons died as infants? While the Prophet was still alive?

Comment: So does that makes any difference, an imam is imam. What was Hassan when ali was imam? Imamzaada? Then so is muhsin

Answer (score 0):

According to **Quran (6:124):**

> *But Allah knows best where to place His Message*

you see that Allah chooses Prophts or Imams to deliver his message. And according to  **Quran (53:1-4):**

> *your companion is neither astray, neither errs,nor does he speak out of desire. Indeed it is not except a Revelation which is revealed*

it is God who directs prophet to do whatever he does. so when in the **Hadith of Jabir b. 'Abd Allah** we read:

> *After the revelation of Uli l-Amr Verse, Jabir b. 'Abd Allah al-Ansari asked the Prophet (s): "O the messenger of God! We know God and His messenger; but we need to know the Uli l-Amr." The Prophet (s) replied: "they are my successors and the imams of Muslims after me. The first is Ali b. Abi Talib, and then Hasan, Husayn, Ali b. al-Husayn, and Muhammad b. Ali known in the Torah as "Baqir", whom you will see at an old age, and whenever you see him, send my regards to him. After Muhammad b. Ali, Ja'far b. Muhammad, Musa b. Ja'far, Ali b. Musa, Muhammad b. Ali, Ali b. Muhammad, Hasan b. Ali, and then his son who is my namesake and has the same kunya as mine. He is the one who will hide from people's view, and his occultation will be so long that only people with firm beliefs will continue to believe in him"*

that means god has chosen **12 and only 12 specific person as Imams** or Khalifas after prophet and directed him to introduce them to others.

visit : http://en.wikishia.net/view/Hadith_of_Jabir_b._%27Abd_Allah#cite_note-1

Answer (score 0):

Imamate is the leadership of the Islamic society and the successor of the Holy Prophet (PBUH) in religious and worldly affairs. Imam's philosophy of existence, transmitting and preserving the religion of Islam, is the correct explanation of religious teachings and guidance of human beings. According to the Shiites, the Imamate is like the prophecy of an appointed official, and whoever is qualified for this position will be appointed by God; As the prophecy continued until the time of the Messenger of God (PBUH) in the generation of Isaac (AS) and not in the generation of his brother Ishmael (AS); Jacob also had 12 children, and the course of prophecy continued in the generation of one of them.
All the children of the Prophet except Fatima (PBUH) died during the life of the Prophet (PBUH) and while they were still children, and the generation of the Prophet (PBUH) continued only through Hazrat Zahra (PBUH). With these interpretations, how were the small children of the Prophet appointed to the Imamate while the Prophet was alive?

In my opinion, your understanding of the issue of Imamate and their place of existence is incomplete and is similar to the concept of princedom. Princes of all ages will still be princes. While the Imamate was considered after the death of the Prophet and as a successor to lead the religious and worldly affairs of the people.
The same is true of Mohsen, the third son of Hazrat Zahra. Mohsen was martyred before he was born. So how could he take the lead in the religious affairs of the people?

https://hawzah.net/fa/Note/View/76416/ and https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA

Answer (score 0):

Why are not Qasim, Abdullah, Ibrahim and Mohsen among the Imams?
According to the Shiites, the Imamate is like the prophecy of an appointed official, and whoever is qualified for this position will be appointed by God; This issue was accepted among the Ahl al-Bayt (as) and their companions because of the knowledge and merit of the infallible Imams. "Imamate" is in fact a divine thing that is determined by God and the one who has the highest position in terms of science, morality, etc. is chosen by God as the Imam because the appointment of the Imam is a favor from God. It is necessary to reform the affairs of His servants and every kindness to God. Therefore, God Almighty appoints the Imam himself. The Imam must be superior and infallible, and he is the only one who knows the infallibility and superiority of individuals.

Ref: https://makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=44&lid=0&mid=406309&catid=

Answer (score -2):

Allah chose the twelve imams before they were even born as you may know, they indeed were very good people and hardly sined but the weren’t infallible or perfect. Infallible people do not make the mistake of looking a wrong look, or anything very small.

Comment: Proof for Allah choosing.